# SQL Trigger: Check if date exists 3 times for user

Tags: sql

I want the trigger to check wether a user already has 3 appointments. If yes. it has to raise an error. The problem is that it has to be a manual date which is entered by the user in the insert statement.

this could be like 23-07-2017 but also 28-08-2017
the date can be random and in the future. But the user cannot have more than 3 appointments on the given date.

Below is the code which i have now but i am stuck on the @datum variable. I do not know how i can give it a date which the user has to put in.

```
create trigger T_Niet_Meer_3_datums
on afspraak
after update, insert
as 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @datum date

(
    select M.Medewerkernr
    from Medewerker M join MedewerkerAfspraak MA on M.Medewerkernr = Ma.medewerkernr 
    join Afspraak A on Ma.afspraaknr = A.afspraaknr
    where datum = @datum 
    group by M.naam
    having count(A.datum) > 3
)
begin 
raiserror('Error: A user is not allowed to have 3 appointments in a single day.',16,1)
rollback transaction
END
END;
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: If this is SQL Server (there are several clues that it might be) you should be aware that triggers fire once per *statement*, not once per row. As such, there may be *more than one date* involved.

Comment: Also, if it's SQL Server, perhaps a check constraint would be a better option.

Comment: Can you **really** use `rollback` inside a trigger in your DBMS? That sounds like a terrible thing to do...